# Tabs keep disappearing on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Tabs keep disappearing on my Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. Below is a screenshot of how the tabs rows look with different window sizes.

On both screenshots, BOTH files are open but when the window's maximized (or larger) I can only see one of the tabs. If I resize the window to make it smaller, the other tab is shown. This happens even if I set pinned tabs to be shown on the same row. I need to say that this is not consistent (it doesn't happen always) and only occurs on one of my dev machines. I've updated the video drivers (NVIDIA) and I even reinstalled Windows on this machine.

[image]

Comment: are you single clicking or double clicking files in your solution explorer?  single click will only show the tab temporarily where as double click will open it permanently.

Comment: I think you're talking about previewing a document. I have that functionality disabled. The only difference between the two screenshots is that on the one where you can see both documents I resized the window to make it a bit smaller.

Comment: Ok, yeah, it was just a guess, but nothing else comes to mind.  I use VS very frequently and, unfortunately, haven't run into that issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to fix it myself but resetting the window layout was the ultimate solution for me.

Go to the **Window** menu and select "**Reset Window Layout**". Then confirm.

You will need to restore all your window layout, such as displaying the Solutions Explorer. All of the special windows are found in the View menu.

Comment: This is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

They don't disappear, a file is not shown on the tab due to size issues when space is constrained.

To get to it, select the `arrow` drop down which will list the 'hidden' files not shown. It is above the yellow triangle.

[image]

Or selct the white triangle to the right which will scroll to the next file which is hidden. Then once moved to the right, there will be a left pointing arrow on the opposite side to move to the left hidden files.

---

From Extensions and Updates download "Productivity Power Tools" which allows tabs to be colored (as shown above) and placed, to the left, right or bottom. I prefer the left, so no files are hidden as they are listed horizontally.

If space is at a premium and one wants to see all of them I find that a vertical display (using the power tools) is the best such as below:

[image]

Comment: I agree with the fact that they are shown on the triangle drop down. However, on my screenshot there's more than enough space for that tab to be shown as it should be shown below the one that's displayed because I have them set on two different rows if they are pinned or not. I've updated the question to explain the situation more clearly.

Comment: @DenisGonzález  The power tools allow one to change the tab sizes. That might help. If you look at my screen shot, I experience the same issue where the space appears to be sufficient but the minimum tab size required causes the windows to not be shown.

Comment: I don't know how helpful that would be though. The issue is when the screen is bigger (maximized). Not when it's smaller.

Comment: @DenisGonzález One can tweak the min and the max sizes of the tabs. So one could find an appropriate size for all to fit.

Comment: @DenisGonzález Maybe showing the tabs on the left side using the power tools could be an option? See my latest edit.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that extension and TabsStudio but I'm so used to working with Visual Studio as it is that using something else slows me down. Thanks for the suggestion ;)

Comment: this is apparently a bug. the tab disappears on my 2560x1440 screen when there's enough space available.